# IBInspectable Creating a Dropdown and better Organization

Tags: swift, xcode6, ibdesignable

In short, I would like to create an `@IBInspectable` property that allows you to select from a list of things in a drop down menu when you are in Storyboards. Also if there is a way to create dividers and better organize the `IBInspectables` I would like to know if this is possible too. In my example, I would like to create regex strings for a phone number so that when I go to the storyboard I can just select the "**phone number**" item in a drop down menu instead of entering a regex string.

Currently I have subclassed a `TextField` so that I can add even more `IBInspectables` to it like regex (which you can see in the picture). So as it stands this is what I have for my subclassed `UITextField`:

```
@IBDesignable public class FRM_TextField: UITextField {


@IBInspectable public var regex : String?

public var isValid : Bool{
    if let unwrappedRegex = regex{
        let applied_regex_expression = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern(unwrappedRegex, options: nil, error: nil)

        let numberOfMatches = applied_regex_expression?.numberOfMatchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(text)))


        if(numberOfMatches > 0 ){
                return true
        }else{
                return false
        }
    }
    return false
}

  public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

  public override init(){
     super.init();
}

  public override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
  }   
}
```

[image: Regex Toolbar]

Comment: For people coming here later, you could improvise/make do with a few BOOL properties that the user can toggle on and off. It's not ideal but it's an option.

Comment: @Jordan Hochstetler +1 for your question did you got the solution for this ?

Comment: @Rakesh still no answer for an array of options but a few of the answers below help with organization

Answer (score 16):

There is no support of any lists or arrays yet.

Currently the following types support `@IBInspectable`

- Int
- CGFloat
- Double
- String
- Bool
- CGPoint
- CGSize
- CGRect
- UIColor
- UIImage

Here is a code with all available IBInspectable's:

```
    @IBInspectable var integer: NSInteger = 10
    @IBInspectable var float: CGFloat = 10
    @IBInspectable var double: Double = 10
    @IBInspectable var string: String = "string"
    @IBInspectable var bool: Bool = true
    @IBInspectable var point: CGPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    @IBInspectable var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
    @IBInspectable var size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Logo")!
```

And it looks in IB like this:

[image]

Comment: [Apple documentation](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devf60c1c514) on supported types: `You can add the IBInspectable attribute to any property in a class declaration, class extension, or category of type: boolean, integer or floating point number, string, localized string, rectangle, point, size, color, range, and nil.`

Answer (score 12):

As far as organization, You can organize it with dividers by naming your properties so that they have the same prefix.

```
@IBInspectable var ValText : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var ValEmail : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var ValCreditCard : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var Positives : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var Money : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var Phone : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var ZipCode : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var Street : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var IPAddress : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var MAC : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var AlphaNum : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var AlphaNumSpaces : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var AlphaNumNoSpaces : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var URL : Bool! = false
@IBInspectable var ValidationType : String! = ""
```

Renders as

[image: IB]

Answer (score 10):

> I would like to create an `@IBInspectable` property that allows you to select from a list of things in a drop down menu when you are in Storyboards.

As far as I know, lists (arrays) are not supported yet.
Suported types so far are:

- `Int`
- `CGFloat`
- `Double`
- `String`
- `Bool`
- `CGPoint`
- `CGSize`
- `CGRect`
- `UIColor`
- `UIImage`

> Also if there is a way to create dividers and better organize the IBInspectables.

I don't think that such thing is possible. But maybe someone has a workaround.

I recommend you to watch [WWDC Session 411 - What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#411).